# Any real contribution of functional analysis to quantum theory as a branch of physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, history

In the last paragraph of [this last paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06630) of Klaas Landsman, you can read:

> Finally, let me note that this was a winner's (or "whig") history, full of hero-worship: following in the footsteps of Hilbert, von Neumann established the link between quantum theory and functional analysis that has lasted. Moreover, partly through von Neumann's own contributions (which are on a par with those of Bohr, Einstein, and Schrodinger), the precision that functional analysis has brought to quantum theory has greatly benefited the foundational debate. However, it is simultaneously a loser's history: starting with Dirac and continuing with Feynman, until the present day physicists have managed to bring quantum theory forward in utter (and, in my view, arrogant) disregard for the relevant mathematical literature. As such, **functional analysis has so far failed to make any real contribution to quantum theory as a branch of physics** (as opposed to mathematics), and in this respect its role seems to have been limited to something like classical music or other parts of human culture that adorn life but do not change the economy or save the planet. On the other hand, like General Relativity, perhaps the intellectual development reviewed
>   in this paper is one of those human achievements that make the planet worth saving.

To balance this interesting debate, if there actually exists real reasons to disagree with above bold sentence of Klaas Landsman, let me ask the following:

What are the real contributions of functional analysis to quantum theory as a branch of physics?

Here "real" should be understood in the sense underlying the above paragraph.

Comment: I guess that the functional analysis role is to put all the arguments used in quantum mechanics on a rigorous mathematical setting. This is obviously very important, as without it, you may never know if you committed some sort of maths taboo based on your intuition.

Comment: @Qmechanic  How this post can be too broad as the expert Klaas Landsman states that there is no such real contribution? I wrote this post to give the opportunity to other experts which disagree with him to write what they consider as a real contribution in order to balance the debate. Are you Klaas Landsman?  Could you please let this post open for few days?

Comment: Functional analysis are used in many areas of quantum theory. Whether one wants to call them _real contributions_ seems to be _primarily opinion-based._ Physicists are very good at inventing intuitive explanations for why their naive calculations fail.

Comment: Tip: If you edit the post it automatically enters the review queue for a second opinion.

Comment: @Qmechanic: OK. I just edited it. I don't know what else I should write now.

Comment: What are you looking for that is not contained in @RishabhJain comment/answer?

Comment: @lcv: his comment could itself be seen as contained in Landsman's view. I am looking for answers from people skeptic of this view. It is interesting (and perhaps revealer of something) that mathematicians [on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/348126/34538) are much more loquacious on this question than physicists here on physics.stackexchange.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Physicist's often come up with mathematics based on intuition to suit their needs even if they are not very well defined mathematically. The best example I can think of this is the Dirac Delta function which dirac made to fit a function that he needed. It took mathematicians almost 30 years to invent the theory of distributions to explain it.  The point is that both works are very important as Dirac delta functions later found use in a lot of places. I think you will find this video useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obCjODeoLVw.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux maybe you would get more answers if you phrased your question differently. Such like: what are the contributions of rigorous functional analysis to quantum mechanics? I have thought about this question myself and couldn't come up with anything except for the following: understanding. I'm not aware of any new phenomenon predicted by FA but the deep understanding that FA brought up has certainly a great value. Of course physicist need to be more practical and cannot spend too much time on the mathematical details but still I think that is an important contribution.